# CodeIgniter 3.1.11 localhost is not working (HTTP ERROR 500)

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

i'am using first time codeigniter .But i know php .

```
const CI_VERSION = '3.1.11';
```

My problem is ; website is working on hosting , im create backup and download my localhost folder.but doesn't work in localhost, i want to work localhost (wamp server). i was get a error HTTP ERROR 500.

localhost url : http://localhost/test/

**I was edit : application/config.php**

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/test/';

**I was update : application/database.php**

what should I do ? What is next step ?

Comment: When you say website is working do you mean it responds when accessed from a domain other than localhost?

Comment: No , website is still working on hosting. i'm download all file hosting download to in my localhost folder and i ' am trying to work localhost

Comment: Is `http://localhost/test` the exact url? Are you using port 80?

Comment: yes exact url http://localhost/test/ im using 80 port

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to install Xampp Software, since wamp server has a issues for proper installation in some systems. This might be the problem.
2. Check .htaccess is available in your root directory. As well as check the permission for the file for index.php in your root directory.
3. Before above 2 steps, make sure to check config.php and database.php has done proper changes.
4. Check the error logs(php_error_log) so that you will find the exact problem.

Comment: thank you for answer. 

1. i did install xampp but same issue still going
2. The .htaccess file does not exist in the root directory. But i checked hosting same the .htaccess file does not exist there too and still work hosting .

Comment: .htaccess:
-----------
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: .htaccess file is hidden in hosting, hidden file will not appear in server based on settings filter!

Comment: i added .htaccess but now url https://localhost/test and same issue .
how i can disable https (ssl redirect ) to wamp server ? or codeigniter

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off->.htaccess file

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/test'; -> is it same as this?

Comment: Still same problem then provide some screenshots of 1. .htaccess file what have u written and 2. error page of the browser and 3. config.php file screenshot

Comment: allright 
https://ibb.co/Dgph89L
https://ibb.co/5kq91Sk
https://ibb.co/GVTrwCf

after change base_url http://localhost/test/ to localhost/test

https://ibb.co/X7ng5VF

Comment: RewriteBase / -> .htaccess file->add After RewriteEngine On and 2. http:// localhost/test in base url not (localhost/test)

Comment: 1. first change :base_url with previous one, type normally in browser url:[link](http://localhost/test) check it is working or not?

Comment: i added problem is still going

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

config.php

$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/test/';  is not working
$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/test/'; is not working

Comment: provide config.php base_url screenshot?

Comment: follow this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/h3wzaua7x7ey90s/screen4.png?dl=0

Comment: yes base_url same your screenshot but still not working.. what is problem i dont know but im going to crazy

Comment: $config['index_page'] = '';// is it same  if not change(config.php) and provide screenshot! it is available in previous screenshot!

Comment: I have updated screenshot - https://www.dropbox.com/s/h3wzaua7x7ey90s/screen4.png?dl=0 check once